# Filter sheet if values in 2 columns are on the same row in a range of values

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

How do I QUERY rows in A:C where values in both ColA and ColB are in any row in range E:F?

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```cpp
=FILTER(A2:C,COUNTIF(E2:E&F2:F,A2:A&B2:B))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, z... This seems to work. If you don't mind a further question: how do I negate the condition? So to show only rows that don't have the combination in E:F?

Comment: Looks like using NOT() before COUNTIF() does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a `QUERY`, but you can try this as an alternative:

`=FILTER({A2:A,C2:C},ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A&B2:B,E2:E&F2:F,0)))`

Answer (score 0):

### Solution using `QUERY`:

Both @Codedabbler's and @z..'s answers get the results you're after but if you absolutely must use `QUERY` and would like to exclude blank rows, you can also try this formula out:

`=QUERY({A:C,E:F},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col1 is not null and Col1 matches Col4 and Col2 matches Col5")`

**EDIT:**

Added a .GIF for clarity:
[image]

Comment: this doesn't really work as `Col1 matches Col4` only compares values in corresponding rows.

Comment: Thanks. On it's own, yes. However, the formula also includes the condition `and Col2 matches Col5`. Values on both `A` and `B` has to match those on `E` and `F` for the query to return a result. I've added a GIF showing how the formula works for better clarity. Do let me know if I misunderstood your statement in any way.

Comment: yeah I understand how the formula works. What I mean is that if the values in E:F are not in the same exact order as the values in A:B the formula will not work.

Comment: Thank you DuuEyn for the answer and the great-looking GIF, however z.. is right, if the values in E:F are not in the same order, it doesn't work.